# How to install scikit-learn, pandas and numpy in a docker image?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, seal

I am doing a project using the [PySEAL](https://github.com/Lab41/PySEAL) library. My project is Machine Learning related so I want to use scikit-learn, pandas and numpy libraries. How can I install these libraries so that I can use them in PySEAL docker container's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `numpy` and `scikit-learn` to PySEAL's [requirements file](https://github.com/Lab41/PySEAL/blob/master/SEALPython/requirements.txt).

Your final requirements file should be:

```
pybind11
cppimport
jupyter
numpy
scikit-learn
```

And run `build-docker.sh` again.

Answer (score 2):

Within your python project, you can freeze the python packages with `pip freeze` and then add the following commands to your Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /var/code/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /var/code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in OpenShift 4.6 environment. So i had to update my requirements.txt and run start-build command again

```
Flask==1.1.1
numpy
pandas
sklearn
```

Then run the below command in order oc cli to update and rebuild the image and restart the pods

```
oc start-build my-app --from-dir . --follow
```